# Data push from DB server to web server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, web-applications

We are using mysqlserver in our web application to track our current
and future jobs state. Currently, our application server [tomcat]
instance periodically sends queries to DB server to find the latest jobs
state. Could you please let me know if there is a way to push the
updated job state from mysql server to web server instead of web server
polling to find the updated state? Please suggest if there are any other better ways to
avoid this polling mechanism. Also, please let me know if there are any DB servers having data push support.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is really how data stores work. MySQL just holds your data and you ask it questions about that data as you need to know. It doesn't report things to you as they happen.

Comment: Is the database MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag both, they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience in SQL Server, but I think following discussions and example would help you.

1. [Calling Web Services from a sql stored procedure, is this
   possible?](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Calling-Web-Services-from-sql-43315.S.49081669)
2. [Calling A Web Service From SQL Server 2005](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2008/11/11/calling-a-web-service-from-sql-server-2005/)

Approach from the second reference can be used as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any facility built in to do this.  How about the code that updates the database also informs the web server?  Or you could inform a service that updates both.

Answer (score 0):

Re: other database servers.  There are different ways of implementing messaging in SQL Server.  You could create a server job that queries job state on a schedule.  Also, [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
may be useful.  Finally, in a .Net application you can use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) to be notified when results of a query change.